# Field must be inside reduxForm() when using symlinked module

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux-form

I am having issues with `redux-form` when developing locally with an npm linked module. I have created an Input component which I intend to use across multiple applications, and so have placed it inside an npm package. In my main application I wrap a component with `reduxForm()` and then import the Input component in to that wrapped component. The Input component initialises the `Field` from `redux-form`.

If I import the Input component from anywhere within my project it works perfectly. Similarly, if I install the package to my node_modules and import it from there it also works perfectly. However, as soon as I import it through a symlink (using `npm link`) it complains with the following error: `Uncaught Error: Field must be inside a component decorated with reduxForm()`

This is strange, it appears to me from the stack trace that it is in fact decorated with `reduxForm()`. I am also running Redux Dev Tools and can see the form has been initialised in state exactly as I expect it to... So the form is there for sure.

Stack trace:

```
react-dom.development.js:17882 
The above error occurred in the <Field> component:
    in Field (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Hoc (created by Field)
    in Field (created by FieldComponent)
    in div (created by Index)
    in Index (created by FieldComponent)
    in FieldComponent (created by Connect(FieldComponent))
    in Connect(FieldComponent)
    in div
    in Col
    in div
    in Row
    in form
    in div (created by Index)
    in Index
    in EditProfileView
    in EditProfile
    in Form(EditProfile)
    in Connect(Form(EditProfile))
    in ReduxForm
    in Hoc
    in ReduxForm
    in Connect(ReduxForm)
    in div
    in Col
    in div
    in Row
    in ContactView
    in Contact
    in Connect(Contact)
    in Route
    in Switch (created by FlatSwitch)
    in FlatSwitch (created by App)
    in Switch (created by FlatSwitch)
    in FlatSwitch (created by App)
    in div (created by Col)
    in Col (created by AppView)
    in div (created by Row)
    in Row (created by AppView)
    in div (created by Container)
    in Container (created by AppView)
    in div (created by AppView)
    in AppView (created by App)
    in App (created by Connect(App))
    in Connect(App) (created by Route)
    in Route (created by withRouter(Connect(App)))
    in withRouter(Connect(App)) (created by App)
    in Auth (created by Connect(Auth))
    in Connect(Auth) (created by Route)
    in Route (created by withRouter(Connect(Auth)))
    in withRouter(Connect(Auth)) (created by App)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (created by App)
    in App
    in Provider
```

Considering this error is only occurring when importing through a symlink I am to assume this may be something to do with the webpack set up. Here are some extracts from my webpack config (the relevant parts I believe):

```
{
    resolve: {
        symlinks: true,
        extensions: ['.jsx', '.js'],
        alias: {
            core: '/Users/MyUser/Projects/@AAG/core',
        },
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(jsx|js)$/,
                include: [
                    '/Users/MyUser/Projects/Hub/src',
                    '/Users/MyUser/Projects/@AAG/core',
                ],
                exclude: [
                    /mapbox-gl/,
                ],
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So you can see that it is set up to transpile from the correct symlinked directory. And in fact it works fine as babel is managing to transpile all of the JSX and all other features of my website (I am importing quite a bit from the `core` alias). `redux-form` is my only bug at this point.

So the form I have created (`EditProfileView` from the stack trace) imports the Input component as follows:

```
import { Input } from 'core/components/Form';
```

The code for this as as follows:

```
const Input = field(InputField);
export { Input };
```

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Field } from 'redux-form';
export function field(Component) {
    const FieldComponent = (props) => {
        ...
        return (
            <div className={`${className} ${block ? s.block : s.inline}`}>
                <Field component={Component} {...props} />
            </div>
        );
    };
    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return { theme: state.theme };
    }
    return connect(mapStateToProps)(FieldComponent);
}
```

And then the `InputField` component does some styling and such and returns a simple input.

I hope all this helps. I have tried to give as much information as possible to help debug this because I really cannot figure out why this is happening. Everything else through the symlink works perfectly, and without the symlink it also works perfectly. I have been looking at this for a long time now and am out of ideas.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I fixed this in the end by just importing the `Field` component and injecting the `Input` component inside the project itself. It's not quite as clean but it works once again with the symlink. If anyone could provide a reason for this bug I would be interested to know.

Answer (score 1):

**Steps**

1. connect to reduxform (to use decorator you have to setup your babel or refer [simple redux Form](https://redux-form.com/8.2.0/examples/simple/))
2. The field which is imported from redux-form must be used inside the form.

thats it, try the following steps.

```
import { Input } from 'core/components/Form';
    The code for this as as follows:

    const Input = field(InputField);
    export { Input };
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

    @reduxForm ({
     form: 'nameOfForm'
    })
    export function field(Component) {
        const FieldComponent = (props) => {
            ...
            return (
                <div className={`${className} ${block ? s.block : s.inline}`}>
                   <form>
                    <Field component={Component} {...props} />
                   </form>
                </div>
            );
        };
        function mapStateToProps(state) {
            return { theme: state.theme };
        }
        return connect(mapStateToProps)(FieldComponent);
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work :( First of all it would complain that only a class could be decorated, so i went about it like this: `export function field(Component) {
 @reduxForm ({ form: 'nameOfForm' })
 class FieldComponent extends React.Component {`. However it still complains that the class is not decorated with `reduxForm`. This behaviour is very strange. I think it has to be something to do with the symlink. As said, if i copy this code and import it from the project it works fine...